# Low FPS after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, steam

recently just installed 16.04, from 14.04 - did a fresh install - erased Hard drive. Everything went fine except now I get a drop of FPS from playing games, specially on steam. In fact, the reason why I switched to 16.04 from 14.04 was that thought that 16.04 had a better handle on FPS. It wasn't doing that before on 14.04. Games thru wine and steam were working fine (14.04) and I was getting 30 Fps, not sure if it's the new kernel. Using Nvidia proprietary drives 340 and Nvidia 710M. If there's any configuration you guys can suggets that would be highly appreciated. I red the forum first on any possible problem with Nvidia on 16.04. All of them was about it not working, well mine's working, it's just not working like it used to. Thanks!

Comment: Try a newer driver - 361 is the latest I think.

Comment: Normally it's recommended to delay upgrading to a new LTS version until after the first point release in this case, 16.04.1 is scheduled for release on  July 21st according to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseSchedule

Comment: Besides video driver issues, another possibility is somehow CPU frequency scaling not increasing the CPU frequency. It is known to be an issue with some games, where they switch CPUs in some odd manor, resulting in the scaling driver not thinking there is enough load to warrant raising the frequency, and the game thinking there isn't enough CPU power to run at a higher frame rate. Try performance mode for whatever CPU frequency scaling driver you are using.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I've been using windows for now. Can't wait for 16.04.1 to be released. Windows is OK but I prefer Ubuntu as my gaming machine. Makes me better at understanding how computers work

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 has a lot of problem with video driver with Linux kernel 4.4.0. I suggest you to install Linux kernel 4.6.0 with [this guide](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/05/install-linux-kernel-4-6-ubuntu-16-04/). In my case my nVidia started to work much better

Comment: Nvidia is very well supported I believe.

Comment: In my case nVidia fan run at maximum speed and I have also some glitch in the Unity bar and my pc, because of these problem, did not want to turn off or restart (as soon as i installed linux kernel 4.6.0 these problems disappeared). Ubuntu developers had announced that there is a compatibility issue on AMD GPUs, but I suspect that also nVidia GPUs had some problem with 4.4.0 kernel